# Scaling a UIView during transitionFromView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, quartz-graphics

I'm using a container UIView to replicate the kind of behavior the iTunes store does when you tap on album artwork and it flips and scales.

Current code looks like:

```
//mainView is 300x300x, smallView is 30x30      

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView transitionFromView:mainView toView:smallView duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];

containerView.frame = CGRectMake(275, 415, 30, 30);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I can't seem to get the content of the containerView to scale during the animation, the frame just closes in on the content. I tried applying some transforms to both the view and the layers and a bunch of other things but I can't seem to get it to behave properly.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the frame, try using a transform instead:

```
- (void)setStartTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform;
- (void)setEndTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform;
```

Something like

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
[UIView transitionFromView:mainView toView:smallView duration:3.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];

//containerView.frame = CGRectMake(275, 415, 30, 30);

[containerView setStartTransform: CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[containerView setEndTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

(You might need to apply a translate to the transform too.)

Comment: Tried it myself and although the scale does work, it still animates as if the frame is closing in on the first view (the content image doesn't scale with its frame).

Comment: Any other solutions for this? I am trying the same thing and struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:mainView
           duration:0.2
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:^{ 
              containerView.frame = CGRectMake(275, 415, 30, 30)
            }
           completion:NULL];
```